# iPad screen mirroring does not work with Mac Book Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, screen-sharing

I'm trying to screen mirror iPad to Macbook Pro, but it does not respond other than showing a waiting cursor.

Here is what I did. I connected the two devices by the iPad charging cable and connected them to the same LAN.Then I chose the screen mirroring option on the upper right corner of iPad. But it then kept me waiting and never responds.

Does anybody know how to fix this? The iPad version is iOSs 13.5 and Mac version is macOS 10.11.6.